# To found or to find?

Tags: word-usage

I read [vox news](https://www.vox.com/recode/21726260/zoom-microsoft-teams-video-conferencing-post-pandemic-coronavirus) and I'm confused if found being used here is correct ?

> Just nine years ago, disaffected Webex engineer Eric Yuan left Cisco **to found** Zoom.

I've tried on Grammarly and it stills show nothing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/found

> Definition of found (Entry 4 of 5)
> transitive verb1: to take the first steps in building
> 2: to set or ground on something solid : BASE
> 3: to establish (something) often with provision for future maintenance
> found an institution

While the past tense of "find" is the same as the present tense of "found", they are different verbs. The verb "found" itself has the past tense "founded".

Comment: True, but is this an ELU standard question?